# Table comments: Table './text/phpbb_posts' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I suddenly crashed my phpbb_posts on phpMyAdmin. Similar [MySQL table is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843776/mysql-table-is-marked-as-crashed-and-last-automatic-repair-failed/53769882#53769882), but there is CLI (command line).

`Table comments: Table './text/phpbb_posts' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed`

phpMyAdmin, ANALYZE TABLE 'phpbb_posts';

- Table './text/phpbb_posts' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
- Table 'phpbb_posts' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
- Corrupt

phpMyAdmin, CHECK TABLE 'phpbb_posts';

- Table is marked as crashed and last repair failed
- Size of datafile is: 214134524       Should be: 0
- Record-count is not ok; is 562662   Should be: 0
- Found 562662 key parts. Should be: 0

phpMyAdmin, REPAIR TABLE 'phpbb_posts';

- Table   Op  Msg_type    Msg_text
- phpbb_posts repair  error   Can't create new tempfile: './text/phpbb_posts.TMD'
- phpbb_posts repair  status  Operation failed

phpMyAdmin, OPTIMIZE TABLE 'phpbb_posts';

- Table './text/phpbb_posts' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
- Table 'phpbb_posts' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
- Corrupt

Host with InterISP.net, so no CLI, only Inter ISP Control panel, FTP and phpMyAdmin.

What can I do?

Comment: system("sudo service mysql start");
exec("sudo service mysql start");
//...has been disabled for security reasons...